# Include jsx components in strings file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**In React and React Native, how can I include jsx components into my strings.js file?**

I have created a `strings.js` file to store all of the copy-text my app uses. This works fine for regular text. However, if the text itself contains other React components, it becomes a problem.

Example:

```
const strings = {
    welcomeScreen: {
        screenTitle: 'Welcome',
        heading: '<TextBold>Thank you</TextBold> for installing our app!',
        paragraph: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit<LineBreakSmall/>consectetur adipisicing.',
    },
};

export default strings;
```

`screenTitle` works, `heading` and `paragraph` do not work. What do I need to change?

PS: I am aware of the JS array notation, but am wondering if there is another way? In particular, with that notation, I would need to import e.g. TextBold and LineBreakSmall in my strings.js file.

Comment: You need to not put React Components as strings. Because they are not strings. The component notation is a jsx construct and it has to be inside a jsx/js file if you ever want it to be transpiled into `react.createElement` calls. There is no other option apart from breaking your strings into sub-strings, that do not have React Components in them

Answer (score 0):

You could try [react-jsx-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-parser#basic-usage---injecting-jsx-as-a-string).

React-html-parser or dangerouslySetInnerHTML would only work for standard html tags, not JSX.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show heading and parameter string as html on your web page, then you can you reacct-html-parser npm library, it will convert your string as html.

Example :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

class HtmlComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    {ReactHtmlParser(string.welcomeScreen.heading)}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {ReactHtmlParser(string.welcomeScreen.paragraph)}
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```